# Equality in distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $A\stackrel{d}{=}C$ and $B\stackrel{d}{=}D$, is it $A+B\stackrel{d}{=}C+D$, where $A,B,C,D$ are dependent random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider for instance all normal distributed variables with unit variance,
$$
B = -A\\
D \text{ independent of } C
$$
as the variance of the first sum is 0, when the variance of the second is 2.

But it becomes true if
$$
(A,B)\stackrel{d}{=}(C,D)
$$
as the sum is then the image of the couple under a deterministic transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general. Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}$, $A = B= C \colon \Omega \to \mathbf R$ the injection $\omega \mapsto \omega$ and $D \colon \Omega \to \mathbf R$ given by $D(\omega) = 1-\omega$. Then $A + B = 2A$ and $C + D = 1$. But a constant and the not constant $2A$ do not have the same distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the following a counter example?

Let $A$ be equally distributed on $\{0,1\}$.
Let $B=1-A$.
Let $C=D=A$.

$A,C$ are obviously equal in distribution.
$B$ is equally distributed on $\{0,1\}$, hence $B,D$ are equal in distribution. 
But $A+B=0$ with probability 1, while $C+D=0$ with probability 0.5.